# Mixing virtual and direct base class

Tags: c++, base-class, virtual-inheritance

Consider the following situation:

```
struct A {};
struct B : virtual A {};
struct D : B, A {};
```

With that approach, I can construct objects of type `D`, or pointers to the `B::A` object through explicit casting, but I have no way of access in any form the direct base class of D because it is ambiguous with `B::A`. If `A` had its own constructors, I could not even construct instances of `D` because I'm not able to call the `A` constructor twice from `D`.

Is there a way that I don't know to use, initialice and access the members of that direct base?

Otherwise, why is even that inheritance combination allowed?

Comment: "why is even that inheritance combination allowed?" - If I were to guess, I'd say "because there's no real reason to not allow it"..